# the meaning of "give someone a case"

Tags: meaning

Rewatching Batman animated series, I came across this line in the episode "on leathery wings", where Bullock wanted to net Batman.

> [Detective Bullock] Just make sure the D.A. 's office can **give me an airtight case**, sir.

The question is the meaning of give me a case.

My first guess was that the case here means argument to support Bullock's arrest of Batman. But why give me(Bullock)? If there is a give in court, the receiver, if I understand correctly, should be the judge and jury. "give Bullock" does not make sense to me.

My second guess was that considering the receiver is Bullock, the case here might mean advocacy or support. But the law dictionary of M-W does not approve this guess.

My third one was that I was taking the sentence too literally and give me a case just means give the case(for me).

My last guess was a wild one. I'm guessing that Bullock pictured a court scene where Harvey Dent would give the case and prove that Batman is guilty, a scene that feels like a show. The show will be "given" to all the audience, including Bullock.

Comment: Your first guess is possibly the right one, but what does "give gesure" mean?

Comment: ah, it is a typo for gesture. I'd better delete it.

Comment: An _airtight case_ just means _a court case you will certainly win_. In other words, Bullock wants to make sure that if they bring Batman to court, the judge/jury will certainly decide he is guilty because they have a lot of evidence. A policeman logically wants arrested criminals to be convicted - otherwise it means he arrested the wrong person. Still, as you correctly mention, the policeman is not legally a party in the case - that doesn't mean he is not interested!

Comment: If I am the detective, I want to minimize the number of arrests I make that go nowhere, for my own reputation.  Indirectly, I want every DA to *give me* an airtight case, even though the work in the court case is the DA's, not mine.  The airtight case is a win for the DA and for me, too.

Comment: Definitely being used in the legal sense here; not in the "give me a case of beer" or the "give me a case of the heebeegeebees" sense.

Answer (score 2):

Bullock (a detective going after Batman) says:

> Just make sure the D.A. 's office can give me an airtight case

From Wikipedia:

> A legal case is a dispute between opposing parties resolved by a
>   court, or by some equivalent legal process. A legal case may be either
>   civil or criminal. In each legal case there is an accuser and one or
>   more defendants.

Bullock wants the office of the District Attorney (which will try the case against Batman in court) to provide a very strong (airtight--no defense) case against Batman, which, yes, will be presented to the court.  But Bullock needs this for his own protection, as he has a reputation for violating rules, although he does not (according to various accounts) take bribes.

Bullock wants to make sure that if he catches Batman, Batman will be convicted.  Otherwise Bullock may be in danger.